# ImportXML "post_name" from an article, having trouble finding proper XPath

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I've been having trouble finding the proper or accurate Xpath for google sheets ImportXML.

Article in question:
https://www.digitaltrends.com/news/this-is-what-a-birthday-party-on-the-iss-looks-like/

Result i'm looking for:
`'post_name': 'this-is-what-a-birthday-party-on-the-iss-looks-like'`

Using the "copy full XPath feature in Chrome Inspect feature, i'm getting:

```
/html/head/script[43]/text()
```

Which does not work with Google Sheet's ImportXML feature.  Can someone guide me through how will i be able to pull this section of the site?

EDIT: I'm trying to retrieve anything within these parameters such as "post name, post title, post id." [View Source[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGjzg.png)

Comment: It would be helpful for you to explain what you are actually trying to achieve.  The content "this-is-what-a-birthday-party-on-the-iss-looks-like" is available in multiple locations in this page, several of which will work just fine with the IMPORTXML function.  There may be easy alternatives compared to digging it out of the script content.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve] and the input html. Do not link to a page, that page may change making the question a moot point. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The page is built in javascript on the client side, not the server side. It is therefore impossible to retrieve information with the IMPORTXML function. You need to read what is included in the script ...

```
function extract(){
  var url='https://www.digitaltrends.com/news/this-is-what-a-birthday-party-on-the-iss-looks-like/'
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var data = source.split('<script>')
  //Logger.log(data[3]) 
  info = "'post_name" + data[3].split('post_name')[1].split(',')[0]
  Logger.log(info)
}
```

Now if you want to retrieve all the information contained in the JSON

```
function extract(){
  var url='https://www.digitaltrends.com/news/this-is-what-a-birthday-party-on-the-iss-looks-like/'
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var data = source.split('<script>')
  //Logger.log(data[3])
  info = data[3].replace(/(\t)/gm,"").replace(/(\n)/gm,"").replace(/(')/gm,"\"").replace(/(: )/gm,":")
  info = info.split('({')[1].split(',});}')[0]
  //Logger.log(info)
  var myData = JSON.parse('{' + info + '}')
  getPairs(eval(myData),'myData')
}
function getPairs(obj,id) {
  const regex = new RegExp('[^0-9]+');
  const fullPath = true
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  for (let p in obj) {
    var newid = (regex.test(p)) ? id + '.' + p : id + '[' + p + ']';
    if (obj[p]!=null){
      if (typeof obj[p] != 'object' && typeof obj[p] != 'function'){
        sheet.appendRow([fullPath?newid:p, obj[p]]);
      }
      if (typeof obj[p] == 'object') {
        getPairs( obj[p], newid );
      }
    }
  }
}
```